# ¿como enviar el ID del ultimo registro de una tabla a un alert()?

Tags: php, javascript, mysql

Buen día!

Soy un novato en PHP. Tengo un formulario el cual hace el INSERT de ciertos datos a una tabla. El procedimiento se realiza correctamente; pero necesito que al hacer el insert me muestre en el mensaje de alert que ya tengo configurado el valor del último ID, es decir, si tengo 8 registros en mi tabla e ingreso un noveno al procesar esos datos me aparezca en el alert "Paciente creado con exito, el expediente es el número 9 - 2020" donde '9' es el ID que se acaba de crear. Tengo una idea, a través de un fetch_array, sin embargo no logro darle forma a la idea. ¿Alguna ayuda? Gracias cracks!

Mi código:

```
    <?php
session_start();
include("conexion.php");

$nombre = $_POST["nombre"];
$direccion = $_POST["direccion"];
$apellidos = $_POST["apellidos"];
$dui = $_POST["dui"];
$deptos = $_POST["deptos"];
$profesion = $_POST["profesion"];
$ciudad = $_POST["ciudad"];
$lugtrab = $_POST["lugtrab"];
$seguro = $_POST["seguro"];
$teltrab = $_POST["teltrab"];
$poliza = $_POST["poliza"];
$correo = $_POST["correo"];
$contactoe = $_POST["contactoe"];
$celular = $_POST["celular"];
$telemergencia = $_POST["telemergencia"];
$estadocivil = $_POST["estadocivil"];
$ingreso = $_POST["ingreso"];
$nacimiento = $_POST["nacimiento"];
$otrainfo = $_POST["otrainfo"];
$activo = $_POST["activo"];
$genero = $_POST["genero"];


$query = "INSERT INTO reg_pacientes (id_paciente, nombre, direccion, apellidos, dui, deptos, profesion, ciudad, lugtrab, seguro, teltrab, poliza, correo, contactoe, celular, telemergencia, estadocivil, ingreso, nacimiento, otrainfo, activo, genero) VALUES (NULL, '$nombre', '$direccion', '$apellidos', '$dui', '$deptos', '$profesion', '$ciudad', '$lugtrab', '$seguro', '$teltrab', '$poliza', '$correo', '$contactoe', '$celular', '$telemergencia', '$estadocivil', '$ingreso', '$nacimiento', '$otrainfo', '$activo', '$genero')";

$success = mysqli_query($connection, $query);

if ($success){

    echo "<script>
            alert('Paciente creado exitosamente. El número de expediente creado es: PENDIENTE-2020.');
                    window.location='admon_newpac.php?ingresar=true'
                  </script>";
}

else{
    header("location: admon_newpac.php?error=true");    
}


?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Después de haber hecho la inserción, debes emplear:
$ultimo_id = mysql_insert_id() + 1;
Luego tambien puedes usar:
"SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID()";
Esta ultima debe ejecutarse despues de haber hecho la inserción del dato y como resultado te devolvera el ultimo Id generado por una única inserción.